# Is there any different JDBC driver to connect TERADATA instead of TERAJDBC.jar?

Tags: jdbc, teradata

I want to connect terada but can i find different jdbc driver instead of terajdbc driver.
I mean I can connect MSSQL with mssql jdbc driver and also jtds jdbc driver.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of one offhand. If you are having specific problems have you considered opening an incident with the Teradata Global Support Center to obtain insight from their engineering staff?

What version of Teradata are you using? Have you tried using a newer version of the JDBC driver? For example Teradata 14's driver with Teradata 13.10 which is certified as backward compatible with Teradata 13.10 (sans Teradata 14 specific features).

Comment: I use terajdbc4.jar and latest teradata express

Comment: why I cant ask question anymore ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans - Might provide some insight but beyond that I'm not sure why.